# How to pass two variable from views to the html in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have taken the objects from the tables into 2 variables. Now i want to send the values of those variables to html using `render_to_response`.

```
def AssetMovement(request):
    print "AssetMovement"
    feature_list = request.session['feature_list']
    featuresgroups = request.session['featuresgroups']
    pplid=request.session['pplid']
    empnm = Asset_Assignment_Employee.objects.filter(Employee__People=pplid)
    print empnm
    id_obj = Asset_Track.objects.all()
    print id_obj
    report = reports.astmvmt_repo(queryset=id_obj)
    report.generate_by(PDFGenerator, filename= 'E:\My Work Location\Example\WorkSpace\\asset_track1\media\\'+str(2)+".pdf")
    return render_to_response('asset_mgmt/astmvmtReport.html',{"contacts":feature_list,'root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'len':len(feature_list)-1,"featuresgroups":featuresgroups,'assertlist':id_obj})
```

Like above, I have send id_obj through 'assertlist' now i want to send empnm object with the same name i.e, 'assertlist' and display in the table.

Kindly try to answer this question as soon as possible. Thank You.

Comment: The context parameters must be of different name, you can not pass two objects with the same name.

Comment: What @aamir-adnan said is true. Also which is your aim with sending two different datasets with the same name? Why don't only identify each one by its own variable name. Well if you can manage `id_obj` and `empnm` elements indistinctly, so merge both `querysets` in an unique `list` and send just one var with all those values.

Comment: -1 not only for the strange question, but also for "kindly try to answer as soon as possible". We're all volunteers here, and we'll answer when we get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the comments above, another option is to use the `{% with %}` template tag to re-assign the variable: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#with